# Incorrect Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Any reason why the below statement doesn't return any results? If I leave out the `where` I get all the records and can clearly see that `VarcharField`s don't match in a number of cases which are the ones I'm trying to find. I've tried swapping ACC and CON in the where and also using `<>` instead of `!=`.

```
SELECT Con.VarcharField, ACC.VarcharField
FROM    
dbo.Contact AS CON
INNER JOIN Account as ACC ON ACC.AccountId = CON.ContactID
WHERE ACC.VarcharField != CON.VarcharField
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is down to null values in the table. Any way around NULL comparisons?

Comment: Did you Check datatypes?

Comment: Got some sample data for this?

Comment: We can't see your data. You're going to have to provide the table structures (are they tables or views, are they the same data type, same collation, etc.?) and at least one example row (including trailing spaces) that you think should match your WHERE clause but doesn't. We're good, but we're not that good.

Comment: Cam you post an http://sqlfiddle.com/ or provide table data?

Comment: Are the cases where you would find a difference maybe cases where one of those columns would be `NULL`? That would explain you not getting results, because you cannot compare with `NULL` you can only check `IS NULL`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc3a1/3

Comment: @DrCopyPaste You are correct, where they don't match the data is null.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste some quick googling seems comparison to NULL isn't possible. Any way around this?

Comment: @windowskm What?, how?, what???. You already have many ways to workaround those comparisons on the answers here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if either side is `NULL` and other is not.

```
SELECT Con.VarcharField, ACC.VarcharField
FROM    
dbo.Contact AS CON
INNER JOIN Account as ACC ON ACC.AccountId = CON.ContactID
WHERE (ACC.VarcharField IS NULL AND CON.VarcharField IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (ACC.VarcharField IS NOT NULL AND CON.VarcharField IS NULL) 
    OR ACC.VarcharField != CON.VarcharField
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3329f/2)**

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons with string fields that might be NULL, I prefer the IsNull() function. Careful. Depends on what your definition of "no value" is, and whether they should match or not match.

```
WHERE IsNULL(ACC.VarcharField, '') != IsNull(CON.VarcharField, '')
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work if the column can contain an empty string.

Comment: It works just fine if an empty string and a NULL mean the same thing. If they don't, you need to find another, neutral value for NULL. In those cases, I sometimes use 'NULL' or '****'. As long as it is a value that doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: If an empty string and NULL mean the same thing (they rarely do), then one or the other shouldn't be allowed.